# KSH Conditional error

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have spent 24 hours trying to figure out who to do a If statement with parameters in KSH.

My script is :

```
VAR=failed
if [[$1 -gt $2]];then
    $VAR=Success
fi

echo $VAR
```

and the output i am getting is

```
$FooBar.ksh 3 1
 FooBar.ksh[2]: [[3:  not found
failed
```

Comment: Please try http://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human proofreading.

Comment: In terms of how to think of this -- `[` is a *command* (literally, a shortcut for the command named `test`, typically implemented as a separate builtin-table entry pointing to the exact same function; similarly `/bin/[` and `/bin/test` are often hardlinks to the same executable), not syntax, and command names need spaces around them. You can't run `ls-l` instead of `ls -l`; same thing applies here. `[[ ]]` is a slightly more interesting case -- it actually *is* syntax -- but still, for purposes of surrounding whitespace, think of it as a command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always put spaces around *test*, so :

```
VAR=failed
if [[ $1 -gt $2 ]]; then
    VAR='Success'
fi

echo "$VAR"
```

And no `$` *sigil* when you assign a value to a variable

#### A bit of *testing*

```
% ksh script.ksh 1 2
failed

% ksh script.ksh 2 1                                                                                        
Success
```

#### Always quote your variables

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

#### A last thing

Avoid using *upper case* for simple script variables, keep these for system variables

Comment: Well I feel like a complete idiot. Thank you so very much